# How can I use the json script on my html in the <script> tag and populate the data in the <img src=???/>

Tags: javascript, html, image, vanilla-forums

how to reach the `JSON` below and populate the `img` tag's `src`?
I was trying to reach it by using the regular method using the dot syntax but it won't work:

```
data.images[0].image
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Slider</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="sliderContainer">
      <img src="data.images[0].image" placeholder="example" />
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js">
      const data = {
        images: [
          { ID: 0, name: 'name1', image: 'images/example1.jpg', link:'#' },
          { ID: 1, name: 'name2', image: 'images/example2.jpg', link:'#' },
        ],
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to run JavaScript code within an HTML attribute value, which won't work. You need to set the image's `src` attribute within the JavaScript code in the `<script></script>` tags

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <title>Slider</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="sliderContainer">
          <img src="" alt="example" />
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          const data = {
            images: [
              { ID: 0, name: 'name1', image: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/07/06/09/37/green-5376289__340.jpg', link:'#' },
              { ID: 1, name: 'name2', image: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/07/06/09/37/green-5376289__340.jpg', link:'#' },
            ],
          };
          document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].setAttribute('src', data.images[0].image);
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Maybe add a part where the images have an ID, and use that? Because this code will fail horrible in real use. Just add a logo in the header, and you have to offset everything +1

Comment: Would also be good to point out that `placeholder` isn't a valid attribute on `img` elements

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
document.getElementByTagName('img').src = "images/example1.jpg";
```

if you want to use javascript variable in HTML you can use Vue.js

Answer (score 0):

you can use the jquery selector for set the image src like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <title>Slider</title>
      </head>
      <body onload="init">
        <div class="sliderContainer">
          <img src="data.images[0].image" placeholder="example"  id="myimg" />
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js">
          const data = {
            images: [
              { ID: 0, name: 'name1', image: 'images/example1.jpg', link:'#' },
              { ID: 1, name: 'name2', image: 'images/example2.jpg', link:'#' },
            ],
          };


function init(){
$("#myimg").attr("src",data.images[0].image);
}
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This question doesn't mention jQuery, and it's not true that jQuery must be used.

Answer (score 0):

select image element by id

```
let img = document.getElementById('image id here');
```

and then

```
img.src = data.images[0].image;
```